# Sort list of colors (palettes) by Hue and Luminosity , using delphi 

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have several list of colors (TColor) stored in arrays which i like sort using the HUE o Luminosity exist any delphi library or component which have this kind of functions or algorithms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi includes a unit called `GraphUtil` which have a function called [`SortColorArray`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/GraphUtil.SortColorArray)

```
procedure SortColorArray(ColorArray: TColorArray; L, R: Integer;
  SortType: TColorArraySortType; Reverse: Boolean = False);
```

this function can sort the colors list by Hue, Saturation, Luminance, Red, Green, Blue.

and you can useit in this way

```
var
 ColorList : TColorArray; 
 i         : Integer;
begin

  SetLength(ColorList,WebNamedColorsCount);
  //fill the list the colors in this case using webcolors
  for i := 0 to WebNamedColorsCount - 1 do
  begin
   ColorList[i].Value:=WebNamedColors[i].Value;
   ColorList[i].Name :='';
  end;
  //sort the colors by HUE
  SortColorArray(ColorList,0,WebNamedColorsCount-1,stHue,False);

  //do your stuff here

end;
```

Comment: +1 I was just to write about these functions! Even if I don't use them myself, I knew they existed!

Comment: +1. Nice! I never noticed this function. When was it added (or has it always been there)?

Comment: @Andreas, I found this function just a couple of months ago, while I wrote an app to change the HUE from some colors. just i wondering why do you prefer write your own functions and don't use this? is because the performance?

Comment: @RRUZ: I want full control. I have my `TRGB`, `THSV`, and `THSL` records that I know exactly how to use. I like to experiment with graphics, and then this additional control is rather nice. In addition, I wrote my functions before I even knew of the `GraphUtils` unit. (IIRC, I wrote the routines back when using Delphi 7...)

Comment: @Ken seems which this function exist since Delphi 2005 http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Changes_to_the_Win32_VCL_in_Delphi_2005_%28VCL_Folder%29

Comment: Thanks very much, is exactly which i looking for.

Comment: @RRUZ: Thanks. I don't do a lot with graphics, and never saw it. I have to spend more time with the source again, I guess. :)

Comment: @Andreas: You should undelete your answer, as it would be useful to people using older (pre-2005) versions of Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

I do

```
type
  TRGB = record
    rgbRed,              // Red intensity in [0, 1]
    rgbGreen,            // Green intensity in [0, 1]
    rgbBlue: double;     // Blue intensity in [0, 1]
  end;

  THSV = record
    hsvHue,             // Hue angle in [0, 360]
    hsvSaturation,      // Saturation in [0, 1]
    hsvValue: double;   // Value in [0, 1]
  end;

function MaxComponent(const Color: TRGB): real;
begin
  with Color do
    result := max(max(rgbRed, rgbGreen), rgbBlue);
end;

function MinComponent(const Color: TRGB): real;
begin
  with Color do
    result := min(min(rgbRed, rgbGreen), rgbBlue);
end;

function Fix360(const a: Real): real;
begin
  result := a;
  if result > 360 then
    while result > 360 do
      result := result - 360
  else if result < 0 then
    while result < 0 do
      result := result + 360;
end;


function RGBToHSV(const Color: TRGB): THSV;
var
  cmax, cmin, cdiff: real;
begin
  cmax := MaxComponent(Color);
  cmin := MinComponent(Color);
  cdiff := cmax - cmin;

  with Color, result do
  begin

    // Hue
    if cmax = cmin then
      hsvHue := 0
    else if cmax = rgbRed then
      hsvHue := (60 * (rgbGreen - rgbBlue) / cdiff)
    else if cmax = rgbGreen then
      hsvHue := (60 * (rgbBlue - rgbRed) / cdiff) + 120
    else
      hsvHue := (60 * (rgbRed - rgbGreen) / cdiff) + 240;

    hsvHue := Fix360(hsvHue);

    // Saturation
    if cmax = 0 then
      hsvSaturation := 0
    else
      hsvSaturation := 1 - cmin / cmax;

    // Value
    hsvValue := cmax;

  end;

end;

function HSVToRGB(const Color: THSV): TRGB;
var
  hi: integer;
  f, q, p, t: real;
begin

  with Color do
  begin

    hi := floor(hsvHue / 60) mod 6;
    f := hsvHue / 60 - floor(hsvHue / 60);
    p := hsvValue * (1 - hsvSaturation);
    q := hsvValue * (1 - f * hsvSaturation);
    t := hsvValue * (1 - (1 - f) * hsvSaturation);

    case hi of
      0: result := RGB(hsvValue, t, p);
      1: result := RGB(q, hsvValue, p);
      2: result := RGB(p, hsvValue, t);
      3: result := RGB(p, q, hsvValue);
      4: result := RGB(t, p, hsvValue);
      5: result := RGB(hsvValue, p, q);
    end;

  end;

end;
```

to convert between RGB and HSV. Now that you easily can get the hue of any colour, sorting should be trivial.

**Update**

How to obtain a `TRGB` from a `TColor`? Just do

```
function PascalColorToRGB(Color: TColor): TRGB;
begin
  Color := GetSysColor(Color);
  with result do
  begin
    rgbRed := GetRValue(Color) / 255;
    rgbGreen := GetGValue(Color) / 255;
    rgbBlue := GetBValue(Color) / 255;
  end;
end;
```

How to obtain a `TColor` from a `TRGB`? Just do

```
function GetPascalColor(const Color: TRGB): TColor;
begin
  with Color do
    result := Windows.RGB(round(255*rgbRed),
      round(255*rgbGreen),
      round(255*rgbBlue));
end;
```